# Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called in

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

foreach ($request->perbaikan_laporan  as $key => $value) {

```
        Perbaikan_laporan::create([
            "jadwal_sidang_id" => $request->input("jadwal_sidang_id"),
            "mahasiswa_id" => $request->input("mahasiswa_id"),
            "dosen_id" => $request->input("dosen_id"),
            "perbaikan_laporan" => $request->input("perbaikan_laporan")[$key],
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you can just call the request data as following, the issue is that you define the input as string first but then you want to use it to get a key when it has already been converted to string.

```
Perbaikan_laporan::create([
        "jadwal_sidang_id" => $request->jadwal_sidang_id,
        "mahasiswa_id" => $request->mahasiswa_id,
        "dosen_id" => $request->dosen_id,
        "perbaikan_laporan" => $request->perbaikan_laporan[$key],
    ]);
```